# Organize root directory using htaccess - urls without extensions and without https

Tags: .htaccess, directory, url-rewriting

I am trying to organize the root directory of my site, because I am gonna create a big number of files in it, so I am using `.htaccess` to help me to do it but my command isn't dynamic and I need to create another line every time when I create a new file.

This is the code of my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Force request to HTTP
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com.br/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect the request of file inside folder 'teste' to base URL - HERE IS THE RULE WHICH ISN'T DYNAMIC
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com.br
RewriteRule ^file2 directory/file2.php [L,QSA]

#Hide and Redirect Extension
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/shtml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule>
```

When I request for this URL: `http://www.example.com.br/file2` I can read the content of the file called `file2.php` which is located in this path: `http://www.example.com.br/directory/teste2.php` everything working perfect but I am gonna put 11k of files inside this folder (`http://www.example.com.br/directory/`) and I cant create a new rule in `.htaccess` for every page, I know there is a form to create the command dynamically, but I tried with no luck.

How do I do it dynamically?

Comment: Is there a pattern?   In your example the request for "teste" followed by a number (`2`) is found in the `teste/` directory.  Is that the general case?  You can strip off the number at the end to know which directory to look for the file?

Comment: Hello @StephenOstermiller thanks for your response, The name "teste" is just an example of name, I will create alot of files like "anotherarquive.php" "anotherone.php" inside the folder called teste/ and I need all thoose files get read like it was in root directory, I am just using this folder to organize my root

Comment: Hey I have updated the question to be more easy to understand the example